# Calculate the Kronecker sum of two matrices

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, linear-algebra, matrix

In the examples below, `A` and `B` will be 2-by-2 matrices, and the matrices are one-indexed.

A [Kronecker *product*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html) has the following properties:

```
A⊗B =  A(1,1)*B   A(1,2)*B
        A(2,1)*B   A(2,2)*B

     =  A(1,1)*B(1,1)   A(1,1)*B(1,2)   A(1,2)*B(1,1)   A(1,2)*B(1,2)
        A(1,1)*B(2,1)   A(1,1)*B(2,2)   A(1,2)*B(2,1)   A(1,2)*B(2,2)
        A(2,1)*B(1,1)   A(2,1)*B(1,2)   A(2,2)*B(1,1)   A(2,2)*B(1,2)
        A(2,2)*B(2,1)   A(2,2)*B(1,2)   A(2,2)*B(2,1)   A(2,2)*B(2,2)
```

A [Kronecker sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html) has the following properties:

```
A⊕B = A⊗Ib + Ia⊗B
```

`Ia` and `Ib` are the [identity matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IdentityMatrix.html) with the dimensions of `A` and `B` respectively. `A` and `B` are square matrices. Note that `A` and `B` can be of different sizes.

```
A⊕B =  A(1,1)+B(1,1)  B(1,2)         A(1,2)         0
        B(2,1)         A(1,1)+B(2,2)  0              A(1,2)
        A(2,1)         0              A(2,2)+B(1,1)  B(1,2)
        0              A(2,1)         B(2,1)         A(2,2)+B(2,2)
```

**Given two square matrices, `A` and `B`, calculate the Kronecker sum of the two matrices.**

- The size of the matrices will be at least `2-by-2`. The maximum size will be whatever your computer / language can handle by default, but minimum `5-by-5` input (5 MB output).
- All input values will be non-negative integers
- Builtin functions that calculate the Kronecker sum or Kronecker products are not allowed
- In general: Standard rules regarding I/O format, program & functions, loopholes etc.

**Test cases:**

```
A =
     1     2
     3     4
B =
     5    10
     7     9

A⊕B =
     6    10     2     0
     7    10     0     2
     3     0     9    10
     0     3     7    13

----

A =
    28    83    96
     5    70     4
    10    32    44
B =
    39    19    65
    77    49    71
    80    45    76

A⊕B =
    67    19    65    83     0     0    96     0     0
    77    77    71     0    83     0     0    96     0
    80    45   104     0     0    83     0     0    96
     5     0     0   109    19    65     4     0     0
     0     5     0    77   119    71     0     4     0
     0     0     5    80    45   146     0     0     4
    10     0     0    32     0     0    83    19    65
     0    10     0     0    32     0    77    93    71
     0     0    10     0     0    32    80    45   120

----

A =
    76    57    54
    76     8    78
    39     6    94
B =
    59    92
    55    29

A⊕B =
   135    92    57     0    54     0
    55   105     0    57     0    54
    76     0    67    92    78     0
     0    76    55    37     0    78
    39     0     6     0   153    92
     0    39     0     6    55   123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>26</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
æ*9Bs2¤×€€/€S;"/€;/
```

Input is a list of two 2D lists, output is a single 2D list. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w6YqOUJzMsKkw5figqzigqwv4oKsUzsiL-KCrDsv&input=&args=W1s3NiwgNTcsIDU0XSwgWzc2LCAgOCwgNzhdLCBbMzksICA2LCA5NF1dLCBbWzU5LCA5Ml0sIFs1NSwgMjldXQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w6YqOUJzMsKkw5figqzigqwv4oKsUzsiL-KCrDsvCsOH4oKsR-KCrGrigJzCtsK2&input=&args=W1tbWzEsIDJdLCBbMywgNF1dLCBbWzUsIDEwXSwgWzcsIDldXV0sCiBbW1syOCwgODMsIDk2XSwgWzUsIDcwLCA0XSwgWzEwLCAzMiwgNDRdXSwgW1szOSwgMTksIDY1XSwgWzc3LCA0OSwgNzFdLCBbODAsIDQ1LCA3Nl1dXSwKIFtbWzc2LCA1NywgNTRdLCBbNzYsICA4LCA3OF0sIFszOSwgIDYsIDk0XV0sIFtbNTksIDkyXSwgWzU1LCAyOV1dXV0).

#### How it works

```
æ*9Bs2¤×€€/€S;"/€;/  Main link.
                     Argument: [A, B] (matrices of dimensions n×n and m×m)

      ¤              Evaluate the four links to the left as a niladic chain.
  9B                 Convert 9 to base 2, yielding [1, 0, 0, 1].
    s2               Split into sublists of length 2, yielding [[1, 0], [0, 1]].
æ*                   Vectorized matrix power.
                     This yields [[A¹, B⁰], [A⁰, B¹]], where B⁰ and A⁰ are the
                     identity matrices of dimensions m×m and n×n.
          /€         Reduce each pair by the following:
        €€             For each entry of the first matrix:
       ×                 Multiply the second matrix by that entry.
            S        Sum the two results, element by element.
                     This yields the Kronecker sum, in form of a n×n matrix of
                     m×m matrices.
               /€    Reduce each row of the outer matrix...
             ;"        by zipwith-concatenation.
                     This concatenates the columns of the matrices in each row,
                     yielding a list of length n of n×nm matrices.
                 ;/  Concatenate the lists, yielding a single nm×nm matrix.
```

Comment: So many euros... your program is rich!

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
9Yb2/q~f{.{_,,_ff=?}:ffff*::.+:~}:..+p
```

Input format is a list containing `A` and `B` as 2D lists, e.g.

```
[[[1 2] [3 4]] [[5 10] [7 9]]]
```

Output format is a single CJam-style 2D list.

[Test suite.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%3AQ%3B%0A%0A9Yb2%2FQ~f%7B.%7B_%2C%2C_ff%3D%3F%7D%3Affff*%3A%3A.%2B%3A~%7D%3A..%2B%0A%0A%7Bs4Se%5B%7Df%25Sf*N*oNoNo%7D%2F&input=%5B%5B%5B1%202%5D%20%5B3%204%5D%5D%20%5B%5B5%2010%5D%20%5B7%209%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B28%2083%2096%5D%20%5B5%2070%204%5D%20%5B10%2032%2044%5D%5D%20%5B%5B39%2019%2065%5D%20%5B77%2049%2071%5D%20%5B80%2045%2076%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B28%2012%2059%2051%5D%20%5B68%2050%2023%2070%5D%20%5B66%2096%2076%2090%5D%20%5B17%2035%2026%2096%5D%5D%20%5B%5B55%2085%2093%2062%5D%20%5B14%2026%2035%2048%5D%20%5B15%2082%2020%2036%5D%20%5B26%2025%2026%2084%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B76%2057%2054%5D%20%5B76%208%2078%5D%20%5B39%206%2094%5D%5D%20%5B%5B59%2092%5D%20%5B55%2029%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B59%2092%5D%20%5B55%2029%5D%5D%20%5B%5B76%2057%2054%5D%20%5B76%208%2078%5D%20%5B39%206%2094%5D%5D%5D) (With more readable output format.)

#### Explanation

This code is an exercise in compound (or infix) operators. These are generally useful for array manipulation, but this challenge exacerbated the need for them. Here is a quick overview:

- `f` expects a list and something else on the stack and maps the following *binary* operator over the list, passing in the other element as the second argument. E.g. `[1 2 3] 2 f*` and `2 [1 2 3] f*` both give `[2 4 6]`. If both elements are lists, the first one is mapped over and the second one is used to curry the binary operator.
- `:` has two uses: if the operator following it is unary, this is a simple map. E.g. `[1 0 -1 4 -3] :z` is `[1 0 1 4 3]`, where `z` gets the modulus of a number. If the operator following it is binary, this will *fold* the operator instead. E.g. `[1 2 3 4] :+` is `10`.
- `.` vectorises a binary operator. It expects two lists as arguments and applies the operator to corresponding pairs. E.g. `[1 2 3] [5 7 11] .*` gives `[5 14 33]`.

Note that `:` itself is always a unary operator, whereas `f` and `.` themselves are always binary operators. These can be arbitrarily nested (provided they have the right arities). And that's what we'll do...

```
9Yb      e# Push the binary representation of 9, i.e. [1 0 0 1].
2/       e# Split into pairs, i.e. [[1 0] [0 1]]. We'll use these to indicate
         e# which of the two inputs we turn into an identity matrix.
q~       e# Read and evaluate input, [A B].
f{       e# This block is mapped over the [[1 0] [0 1]] list, also pushing
         e# [A B] onto the stack for each iteration.
  .{     e#   The stack has either [1 0] [A B] or [0 1] [A B]. We apply this
         e#   block to corresponding pairs, e.g. 1 A and 0 B.
    _,   e#     Duplicate the matrix and get its length/height N.
    ,_   e#     Turn into a range [0 1 ... N-1] and duplicate it.
    ff=  e#     Double f on two lists is an interesting idiom to compute an
         e#     outer product: the first f means that we map over the first list
         e#     with the second list as an additional parameter. That means for
         e#     the remaining operator the two arguments are a single integer
         e#     and a list. The second f then maps over the second list, passing
         e#     in the the number from the outer map as the first parameter.
         e#     That means the operator following ff is applied to every possible
         e#     pair of values in the two lists, neatly laid out in a 2D list.
         e#     The operator we're applying is an equality check, which is 1
         e#     only along the diagonal and 0 everywhere else. That is, we've
         e#     created an NxN identity matrix.
    ?    e#     Depending on whether the integer we've got along with the matrix
         e#     is 0 or 1, either pick the original matrix or the identity.
  }
         e#   At this point, the stack contains either [A Ib] or [Ia B]. 
         e#   Note that A, B, Ia and Ib are all 2D matrices.
         e#   We now want to compute the Kronecker product of this pair.
  :ffff* e#   The ffff* is the important step for the Kronecker product (but
         e#   not the whole story). It's an operator which takes two matrices
         e#   and replaces each cell of the first matrix with the second matrix
         e#   multiplied by that cell (so yeah, we'll end up with a 4D list of
         e#   matrices nested inside a matrix).
         e#   The leading : is a fold operation, but it's a bit of a degenerate
         e#   fold operation that is only used to apply the following binary operator
         e#   to the two elements of a list.
         e#   Now the ffff* works essentially the same as the ff= above, but
         e#   we have to deal with two more dimensions now. The first ff maps
         e#   over the cells of the first matrix, passing in the second matrix
         e#   as an additional argument. The second ff then maps over the second
         e#   matrix, passing in the cell from the outer map. We multiply them
         e#   with *.
         e#   Just to recap, we've essentially got the Kronecker product on the
         e#   stack now, but it's still a 4D list not a 2D list.
         e#   The four dimensions are:
         e#     1. Columns of the outer matrix.
         e#     2. Rows of the outer matrix.
         e#     3. Columns of the submatrices.
         e#     4. Rows of the submatrices.
         e#   We need to unravel that into a plain 2D matrix.
  ::.+   e#   This joins the rows of submatrices across columns of the outer matrix.
         e#   It might be easiest to read this from the right:
         e#     +    Takes two rows and concatenates them.
         e#     .+   Takes two matrices and concatenates corresponding rows.
         e#     :.+  Takes a list of matrices and folds .+ over them, thereby
         e#          concatenating the corresponding rows of all matrices.
         e#     ::.+ Maps this fold operation over the rows of the outer matrix.
         e#   We're almost done now, we just need to flatten the outer-most level
         e#   in order to get rid of the distinction of rows of the outer matrix.
  :~     e#   We do this by mapping ~ over those rows, which simply unwraps them.
}
         e# Phew: we've now got a list containing the two Kronecker products
         e# on the stack. The rest is easy, just perform pairwise addition.
:..+     e# Again, the : is a degenerate fold which is used to apply a binary
         e# operation to the two list elements. The ..+ then simply vectorises
         e# addition twice, such that we add corresponding cells of the 2D matrices.
p        e# All done, just pretty-print the matrix.
```

Comment: fffffffffff what on earth... I hope that survives golfing so that you explain it eventually :P

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman `:ffff*` might be the longest (compound) operator I've ever used in CJam... For one *more* byte one could go even crazier though: `9Yb2/Q~f.{\{,,_ff=}&}::ffff*:::.+::~:..+p` (and yeah, will add an explanation when I'm done golfing).

Answer (score 4):

## J - <s>38</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
i=:=@i.@#
[:,./^:2(*/i)+(*/~i)~
```

### Usage

```
   f =: [:,./^:2(*/i)+(*/~i)~
   (2 2 $ 1 2 3 4) f (2 2 $ 5 10 7 9)
6 10 2  0
7 10 0  2
3  0 9 10
0  3 7 13
   (3 3 $ 28 83 96 5 70 4 10 32 44) f (3 3 $ 39 19 65 77 49 71 80 45 76)
67 19  65  83   0   0 96  0   0
77 77  71   0  83   0  0 96   0
80 45 104   0   0  83  0  0  96
 5  0   0 109  19  65  4  0   0
 0  5   0  77 119  71  0  4   0
 0  0   5  80  45 146  0  0   4
10  0   0  32   0   0 83 19  65
 0 10   0   0  32   0 77 93  71
 0  0  10   0   0  32 80 45 120
   (3 3 $ 76 57 54 76 8 78 39 6 94) f (2 2 $ 59 92 55 29)
135  92 57  0  54   0
 55 105  0 57   0  54
 76   0 67 92  78   0
  0  76 55 37   0  78
 39   0  6  0 153  92
  0  39  0  6  55 123
```

Comment: Using matrix division will fail if one of the matrices is singular. For example, `(2 2 $ 1 2 3 4) f (2 2 $ 1 1 1 1)` will raise a domain error.

Comment: @Dennis good catch, I was only testing against random values `? 4 4 $ 100` . I'm not sure if there's a way to make use of dyad compose `x f&g y = (g x) f (g y)` or something else here.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
A%B=hvcat(sum(A^0),sum(i->map(a->a*B^i,A'^-~-i),0:1)...)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=QSVCPWh2Y2F0KHN1bShBXjApLHN1bShpLT5tYXAoYS0-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&input=)

#### How it works

- For matrices **A** and **B**, `map(a->a*B,A')` computes the Kronecker product **A⊗B**.

  The result is a vector of matrix blocks with the dimensions of **B**.

  We have to transpose **A** (with `'`) since matrices are stored in column-major order.
- Since bitwise NOT with two's complement satisfies the identity **~n = -(n + 1)** for all integers **n**, we have that **-~-n = -(~(-n)) = --((-n) + 1) = 1 - n**, so **-~-0 = 1** and **-~-1 = 0**.

  This way the anonymous function `i->map(a->a*B^i,A'^-~-i)` applies the above map to **B⁰** (the identity matrix with **B**'s dimensions) and **A¹ = A** when **i = 0**, and to **B¹** and **A⁰** when **i = 1**.
- `sum(i->map(a->a*B^i,A'^-~-i),0:1)` sums over **{0,1}** with the above anonymous function, computing the Kronecker sum **A⊕B** as **A¹⊗B⁰ + A⁰⊗B¹**.

  The result is a vector of matrix blocks with the dimensions of **B**.
- `sum(A^0)` computes the sum of all entries of the identity matrix of **A**'s dimensions. For an **n×n** matrix **A**, this yields **n**.
- Finally, `hvcat(sum(A^0),sum(i->map(a->a*B^i,A'^-~-i),0:1)...)` concatenates the matrix blocks that form **A⊕B**.

  With first argument **n**, `hvcat` concatenates **n** matrix blocks horizontally, and the resulting (larger) blocks vertically.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 102

```
->a,b{r=0..-1+a.size*q=b.size
r.map{|i|r.map{|j|(i/q==j/q ?b[i%q][j%q]:0)+(i%q==j%q ?a[i/q][j/q]:0)}}}
```

**In test program**

```
f=->a,b{r=0..-1+a.size*q=b.size
r.map{|i|r.map{|j|(i/q==j/q ?b[i%q][j%q]:0)+(i%q==j%q ?a[i/q][j/q]:0)}}}

aa =[[1,2],[3,4]]
bb =[[5,10],[7,9]]
f[aa,bb].each{|e|p e}
puts

aa =[[28,83,96],[5,70,4],[10,32,44]]
bb =[[39,19,65],[77,49,71],[80,45,76]]
f[aa,bb].each{|e|p e}
puts

aa =[[76,57,54],[76,8,78],[39,6,94]]
bb =[[59,92],[55,29]]
f[aa,bb].each{|e|p e}
puts
```

Requires two 2D arrays as input and returns a 2D array.

There are probably better ways of doing this: using a function to avoid repetition; using a single loop and printing the output. Will look into them later.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 109

Built upon the answer to [the other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78797/calculate-the-kronecker-product/78802#78802)

```
(a,b)=>a.map((a,k)=>b.map((b,i)=>a.map((y,l)=>b.map((x,j)=>r.push(y*(i==j)+x*(k==l))),t.push(r=[]))),t=[])&&t
```

**Test**

```js
f=(a,b)=>a.map((a,k)=>b.map((b,i)=>a.map((y,l)=>b.map((x,j)=>r.push(y*(i==j)+x*(k==l))),t.push(r=[]))),t=[])&&t

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

function show(label, mat)
{
  console.log(label)
  console.log(mat.join`\n`)
}

;[ 
  {a:[[1,2],[3,4]], b:[[5,10],[7,9]]},
  {a:[[28,83,96],[5,70,4],[10,32,44]], b:[[39,19,65],[77,49,71],[80,45,76]]},
  {a:[[76,57,54],[76,8,78],[39,6,94]], b:[[59,92],[55,29]]}
].forEach(t=>{
  show('A',t.a)  
  show('B',t.b)
  show('A⊕B',f(t.a,t.b))
  show('B⊕A',f(t.b,t.a))  
  console.log('-----------------')
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```