# Calculate the Kronecker Product

Tags: code-golf, math, linear-algebra, matrix

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78615/calculate-the-kronecker-sum-of-two-matrices), but very different.

---

In the examples below, \$A\$ and \$B\$ will be \$2\times2\$ matrices, and the matrices are one-indexed.

A [Kronecker *product*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html) has the following properties:

```
A⊗B =  A(1,1)*B   A(1,2)*B
        A(2,1)*B   A(2,2)*B

     =  A(1,1)*B(1,1)   A(1,1)*B(1,2)   A(1,2)*B(1,1)   A(1,2)*B(1,2)
        A(1,1)*B(2,1)   A(1,1)*B(2,2)   A(1,2)*B(2,1)   A(1,2)*B(2,2)
        A(2,1)*B(1,1)   A(2,1)*B(1,2)   A(2,2)*B(1,1)   A(2,2)*B(1,2)
        A(2,2)*B(2,1)   A(2,2)*B(1,2)   A(2,2)*B(2,1)   A(2,2)*B(2,2)
```

**Challenge: Given two matrices, \$A\$ and \$B\$, return \$A\otimes B\$.**

- The size of the matrices will be at least \$1\times1\$. The maximum size will be whatever your computer / language can handle by default, but minimum \$5\times5\$ input.
- All input values will be non-negative integers
- Builtin functions that calculate Kronecker products or [Tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)/[Outer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) products are not allowed
- In general: Standard rules regarding I/O format, program & functions, loopholes etc.

**Test cases:**

```
A =   
     1     2
     3     4    
B =    
     5     6
     7     8    
A⊗B =    
     5     6    10    12
     7     8    14    16
    15    18    20    24
    21    24    28    32

B⊗A =    
     5    10     6    12
    15    20    18    24
     7    14     8    16
    21    28    24    32
------------------------
A =    
     1
     2
B =    
     1     2

A⊗B =    
     1     2
     2     4
------------------------
A =    
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
    
B =    
     1     1
     0     1
    
A⊗B  =    
    16    16     2     2     3     3    13    13
     0    16     0     2     0     3     0    13
     5     5    11    11    10    10     8     8
     0     5     0    11     0    10     0     8
     9     9     7     7     6     6    12    12
     0     9     0     7     0     6     0    12
     4     4    14    14    15    15     1     1
     0     4     0    14     0    15     0     1

B⊗A =    
    16     2     3    13    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1     4    14    15     1
     0     0     0     0    16     2     3    13
     0     0     0     0     5    11    10     8
     0     0     0     0     9     7     6    12
     0     0     0     0     4    14    15     1
------------------------

A = 2
B = 5
A⊗B = 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
×€€;"/€;/
```

Uses [Büttner's Algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78798/48934) (`ü` pronounced when trying to make an `ee` sound [as in meet] in the mouth-shape of an `oo` sound [as in boot]).

The `;"/€;/` is inspired by [Dennis Mitchell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78668/48934). It was originally `Z€F€€;/` (which costs one more byte).

- [Test case 1](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5figqzigqw7Ii_igqw7Lw&input=&args=W1sxLDJdLFszLDRdXQ+W1s1LDZdLFs3LDhdXQ)
- [Test case 2](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5figqzigqw7Ii_igqw7Lw&input=&args=W1sxXSxbMl1d+W1sxLDJdXQ)
- [Test case 3](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5figqzigqw7Ii_igqw7Lw&input=&args=W1sxNiwyLDMsMTNdLFs1LDExLDEwLDhdLFs5LDcsNiwxMl0sWzQsMTQsMTUsMV1d+W1sxLDFdLFswLDFdXQ)
- [Test case 4](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w5figqzigqw7Ii_igqw7Lw&input=&args=W1syXV0+W1s1XV0)

Comment: Or, in IPA, /y/

Comment: Not every person knows IPA.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how to pronounce Martin's last name. It's super relevant. :P

Comment: Well it's how I show respect...

Comment: `;/` can be `Ẏ` now. (feature postdates challenge?)

Answer (score 7):

### CJam, 13 bytes

```
{ffff*::.+:~}
```

This is an unnamed block that expects two matrices on top of the stack and leaves their Kronecker product in their place.

[Test suite.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~ffff*%3A%3A.%2B%3A~%0A%0A%7Bs4Se%5B%7Df%25Sf*N*oNoNo%7D%2F&input=%5B%5B1%202%5D%20%5B3%204%5D%5D%20%5B%5B5%206%5D%20%5B7%208%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B5%206%5D%20%5B7%208%5D%5D%20%5B%5B1%202%5D%20%5B3%204%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%5D%20%5B2%5D%5D%20%5B%5B1%202%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%202%5D%5D%20%5B%5B1%5D%20%5B2%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B16%202%203%2013%5D%20%5B5%2011%2010%208%5D%20%5B9%207%206%2012%5D%20%5B4%2014%2015%201%5D%5D%20%5B%5B1%201%5D%20%5B0%201%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B1%201%5D%20%5B0%201%5D%5D%20%5B%5B16%202%203%2013%5D%20%5B5%2011%2010%208%5D%20%5B9%207%206%2012%5D%20%5B4%2014%2015%201%5D%5D)

#### Explanation

This is just the Kronecker product part [from the previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78621/8478), therefore I'm here just reproducing the relevant parts of the previous explanation:

Here is a quick overview of CJam's infix operators for list manipulation:

- `f` expects a list and something else on the stack and maps the following *binary* operator over the list, passing in the other element as the second argument. E.g. `[1 2 3] 2 f*` and `2 [1 2 3] f*` both give `[2 4 6]`. If both elements are lists, the first one is mapped over and the second one is used to curry the binary operator.
- `:` has two uses: if the operator following it is unary, this is a simple map. E.g. `[1 0 -1 4 -3] :z` is `[1 0 1 4 3]`, where `z` gets the modulus of a number. If the operator following it is binary, this will *fold* the operator instead. E.g. `[1 2 3 4] :+` is `10`.
- `.` vectorises a binary operator. It expects two lists as arguments and applies the operator to corresponding pairs. E.g. `[1 2 3] [5 7 11] .*` gives `[5 14 33]`.

```
ffff*  e# This is the important step for the Kronecker product (but
       e# not the whole story). It's an operator which takes two matrices
       e# and replaces each cell of the first matrix with the second matrix
       e# multiplied by that cell (so yeah, we'll end up with a 4D list of
       e# matrices nested inside a matrix).
       e# Now the ffff* is essentially a 4D version of the standard ff* idiom
       e# for outer products. For an explanation of ff*, see the answer to
       e# to the Kronecker sum challenge.
       e# The first ff maps over the cells of the first matrix, passing in the 
       e# second matrix as an additional argument. The second ff then maps over 
       e# the second matrix, passing in the cell from the outer map. We 
       e# multiply them with *.
       e# Just to recap, we've essentially got the Kronecker product on the
       e# stack now, but it's still a 4D list not a 2D list.
       e# The four dimensions are:
       e#   1. Columns of the outer matrix.
       e#   2. Rows of the outer matrix.
       e#   3. Columns of the submatrices.
       e#   4. Rows of the submatrices.
       e# We need to unravel that into a plain 2D matrix.
::.+   e# This joins the rows of submatrices across columns of the outer matrix.
       e# It might be easiest to read this from the right:
       e#   +    Takes two rows and concatenates them.
       e#   .+   Takes two matrices and concatenates corresponding rows.
       e#   :.+  Takes a list of matrices and folds .+ over them, thereby
       e#        concatenating the corresponding rows of all matrices.
       e#   ::.+ Maps this fold operation over the rows of the outer matrix.
       e# We're almost done now, we just need to flatten the outer-most level
       e# in order to get rid of the distinction of rows of the outer matrix.
:~     e# We do this by mapping ~ over those rows, which simply unwraps them.
```

Comment: Your code almost looks like an IPv6 address

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB / Octave, <s>83</s> 42 Bytes

Saved **41** bytes, thanks to  FryAmTheEggman!

```
@(A,B)cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n)n*B,A,'un',0))
```

[Test it here!](https://ideone.com/SASqUt)

**Breakdown**

`arrayfun` is a disguised for-loop that multiplies `n*B`, for a variable `n` defined by the second argument. This works because looping through a 2D matrix is the same as looping through a vector. I.e. `for x = A` is the same as `for x = A(:)`.

`'un',0` is equivalent to the more verbose `'UniformOutput', False`, and specifies that the output contains cells instead of scalars.

`cell2mat` is used to convert the cells back to a numeric matrix, which is then outputted.

Comment: You should clarify that `arrayfun` loops linearly as you say, as if the matrix were a vector, but `for` does _not_ (it loops over _columns_ of the array)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
JEsMs*RRRRJ
```

Translation of [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78799/48934), which is based on [Büttner's Algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78798/48934) (`ü` pronounced when trying to make an `ee` sound [as in meet] in the mouth-shape of an `oo` sound [as in boot]).

[Try it online (test case 1)!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JEsMs*RRRRJ&input=%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%5B7%2C8%5D%5D&debug=0)

#### Bonus: calculate `B⊗A` in the same number of bytes

```
JEsMs*LRLRJ
```

[Try it online (test case 1)!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JEsMs*LRLRJ&input=%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B3%2C4%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B5%2C6%5D%2C%5B7%2C8%5D%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
A%B=hvcat(sum(A^0),map(a->a*B,A')...)
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=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&input=)

#### How it works

- For matrices **A** and **B**, `map(a->a*B,A')` computes the Kronecker product **A⊗B**.

  The result is a vector of matrix blocks with the dimensions of **B**.

  We have to transpose **A** (with `'`) since matrices are stored in column-major order.
- `sum(A^0)` computes the sum of all entries of the identity matrix of **A**'s dimensions. For an **n×n** matrix **A**, this yields **n**.
- With first argument **n**, `hvcat` concatenates **n** matrix blocks horizontally, and the resulting (larger) blocks vertically.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>98</s> 86 bytes

```r
function(x,y,`+`=array)aperm(apply(x,1:2,`*`,y)+c(w<-dim(y),v<-dim(x)),c(1,3,2,4))+v*w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/dCoMwDEbvfYreCM2MsKj7RS8U9gJju2/nNhCmk@LUPr1LJwMLh4Svh6Q1k/LlCL4SaSim56cpu@rdyBEtqkBl2hhtQbcPU0vdti/LN3SMUK0UWghKOaThvaqlBeznbgTAUhLGGGECEPSrYcrd8Fp3phqlV0pBWxQiYmKGYvQEnw0KImbNmdjP2YH7HeN8iuYsYcexcR4BNuY9ZAnerKuX8/UEXrHY595CuMa/yWuXav77feEVv5pPXw)

Reimplementation of `.kronecker` and `outer` for matrices. <s>I do think there's a golfier approach out there, maybe using `apply`?</s> 6 bytes golfed using `apply` and `array` thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)!

The builtins are `%x%` for `kronecker(A,B,"*")` and `%o%` for `outer(A,B,"*")`.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 120 bytes

```r
function(A,B){l=list()
a=dim(A)
for(i in 1:a[2]-1)l[[i+1]]<-do.call(rbind,lapply(A,"*",B)[1:a+a[2]*i])
do.call(cbind,l)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3disIwEEbv8xSDV4lOxam6P2IvWvAFZPeq9CKmFAZiKtkuu7Lss9eJRTBwyPBxZr44lrDP4GyHyL9aOQ30ggC5sBZojQrkbRGIhJVk8DZl7zK/CsmnfMo24iS2ySODIfY/xQZP1/R/HD8PRlVPfU4TEq7wYUrts9oldey@gxu4D7rEyvz5wvPXoI2yRctnXYrVR83AAWhn67zJyPi65gU1zT5r@6Wz3ut44tCit5eLv8qd2Xwmt2pZWKSVOTdGPVQ3qeZ/7O6NqtMVlma8AQ)

Naive approach: calculate the subarrays \$a_{ij}B\$ and bind them together in the appropriate order. There are probably golfs here too, but I don't think it'll be shorter than the one above.

Comment: This is funny!  I got almost exactly the same answer yesterday (when your edit put this post to the top), but it seemed so un-golfy I didn't even submit it...!  My best attempt was [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY5LDoNADEP3nGSCvCD82iLNXQiUSojy0YgCc/pp6KJiZSfPluzC4Oapa4fO2fD6TO3az5M54LHZZz@ag7D/jCeIFefEkxhZOjeaU5e31zRXKeq4hoZas2OjUxkZUuTqt3inIHaU1fWHUVKiwAO5YmbcwLlGOUEJLsAZ7mAlpN2oubSQgM93StF/tBE017OBUPgC)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen _there's_ the better version with `apply`. I knew it was out there, just couldn't wrap my head around it. Feel free to post it yourself.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen PS [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7rCoMwFIP/@yQ9moHH2y7Md@mxcyDOC8WpffquYzD8l@RLINb3dhpb07e29s/3aJZuGtUOB53oWqwVRzK3dlAyzy8XCN8y6FjDUWLUdj89ukE5wvpTOxGMYuTIUBAla7x5qQdZbLerACqUuKIIlBlncBGanKICl@AcF3AgFKZRc1ghBX/jjKL/XSVojraBkP8A)

Comment: Hmm...  That's getting good, but...  I think you should just incorporate these into your answer, instead of outgolfing yourself in your own comments...!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen fair enough! But I do think it's a shame such a matrix-friendly language is longer than the JS answer...

Comment: I completely agree, but, if it's any consolation, if JS 'map' was called 'apply' (like in R), the JS answer would be 87 bytes long...

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79

Straightforward implementation with nested looping

```js
(a,b)=>a.map(a=>b.map(b=>a.map(y=>b.map(x=>r.push(y*x)),t.push(r=[]))),t=[])&&t
```

**Test**

```js
f=(a,b)=>a.map(a=>b.map(b=>a.map(y=>b.map(x=>r.push(y*x)),t.push(r=[]))),t=[])&&t

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

function show(label, mat)
{
  console.log(label)
  console.log(mat.join`\n`)
}

;[ 
  {a:[[1,2],[3,4]],b:[[5,6],[7,8]] },
  {a:[[1],[2]],b:[[1,2]]},
  {a:[[16,2,3,13],[5,11,10,8],[9,7,6,12],[4,14,15,1]],b:[[1,1],[0,1]]},
  {a:[[2]],b:[[5]]}
].forEach(t=>{
  show('A',t.a)  
  show('B',t.b)
  show('A⊗B',f(t.a,t.b))
  show('B⊗A',f(t.b,t.a))  
  console.log('-----------------')
})
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 10 bytes

This is one possible implementation.

```
[:,./^:2*/
```

## J, 13 bytes

This is a similar implementation, but instead uses J's ability to define ranks. It applies `*` between each element on the LHS with the entire RHS.

```
[:,./^:2*"0 _
```

### Usage

```
   f =: <either definition>
    (2 2 $ 1 2 3 4) f (2 2 $ 5 6 7 8)
 5  6 10 12
 7  8 14 16
15 18 20 24
21 24 28 32
   (2 1 $ 1 2) f (1 2 $ 1 2)
1 2
2 4
   2 f 5
10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/)

```apl
{⍪/,/⍺×⊂⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR7yp9Hf1HvbsOT3/U1fSod2vt/7RHbRMe9fY96mp@1LvmUe@WQ@uNH7VNfNQ3NTjIGUiGeHgG/3cEqWmbqGGoYKSpYaxgosnlBBUxVTDT1DBXsNDkclRIU3ACAA)

#### How it Works

```apl
{  ...   }  ⍝ dfn that takes ⍺=A and ⍵=B
     ⍺×⊂⍵   ⍝ Product of each element of A with all of matrix B
            ⍝ Gives a nested array: an matrix of matrices
   ./       ⍝ Join rows
 ⍪/         ⍝ Join columns
```